# Illegal characters in URLs

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some old permalinks (posts, pages, tags) that contain now-illegal characters in them - and these aren't working anymore.

In previous versions of WP it was allowed to use the non-latin characters, but that changed in newer versions.

Is there any way to clean the database from these permalinks (converting them to allowed format)?

Comment: nothing has changed in the url standard.

Comment: How will you 'convert' a non-Latin character to a Latin one? You could try using regexprs to remove the said characters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the wordpress function  `sanitize_title( $title);` in all  your posts

```
$posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => array('post', 'page'))
foreach($posts as $post)
{

 $post[post_name] = sanitize_title( $title);

  wp_update_post( $post );

 }
```

Comment: any idea how to do that with tags as well?

Comment: maybe with $terms = get_terms('post_tag') and `foreach($terms as $term){ wp_update_term( $term->term_id, 'post_tag',array('slug'=> sanitize_title($term->name)) )} `

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the characters are, and what you want to replace them with, you could write a simple PHP script to grab the data from the database, then use `preg_replace()` to fix the characters on the PHP side, then update the table with the fix. Here's a quick example I came up with:

```
$query = "SELECT field, primarykey FROM table WHERE field LIKE "(weird character)";
/* run the query, blah blah */
$result = mysql_query($query);
$weird_character = "/weird character/";
$good_character = "good character";
$replace = "UPDATE table SET field='$field' WHERE field='$row['field']'";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$field = preg_replace($bad_character, $good_character, $row['field']);
$replace_result = mysql_query($replace);
}
```

If you have an enormous number of links, this will take forever. If its a small amount, this should be efficient enough, you'll only run it once anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a standard wordpress function esc_url_raw if you need to modify urls of course. This function can eliminate invalid characters, remove dangerous characters, and verify the url has a proper protocol set (http, https, ftp, and so on):

```
esc_url_raw( $current_url );
```